# pyspark how to speed up toPandas() method

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a rather large pyspark dataframe that needs to be converted to pandas (with the toPandas() method) so that I have an easier time creating a csv in my s3 bucket.  However, when I try to run this, the script just sits there for a very long time before I get an error which is usually "Killed by external signal".  toPandas() works fine on other smaller pyspark data frames, so it's because mine is so large that I'm having trouble.  In addition, I've applied various transformations, including limit(100), which should leave me with only a data frame with only 100 rows which should mean that toPandas() should run very quick, but it still runs slow.

I found this article: https://bryancutler.github.io/toPandas/  which gave me the following snippet of code:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.execution.arrow.enabled","true")
```

But that doesn't seem to help me either.  So, given that my data frame is so large, is there another way to either get this pyspark data frame into pandas or to bypass Pandas all together and save directly to the s3 bucket?

Any help or ideas would be great!

Thanks

Edit:

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pandas as pd

words    = {"blah", "blarg", "python", "thisshouldn'texist"}
maxInter = 3 # maximum intermediate words between the target words

wordSpan = len(words)+maxInter*(len(words)-1)

anyWord  = "|".join(words)
allWords = "".join(r"(?=(\w+\W*){0,SPAN}WORD\b)".replace("WORD",w) 
                    for w in words)
allWords = allWords.replace("SPAN",str(wordSpan-1))
                    
pattern = r"\bALL(\b(ANY)(\W+\w+\W*){0,INTER}){COUNT,COUNT}"
pattern = pattern.replace("COUNT",str(len(words)))
pattern = pattern.replace("INTER",str(maxInter))
pattern = pattern.replace("ALL",allWords)
pattern = pattern.replace("ANY",anyWord)

filtered = df.withColumn("attachment_text", regexp_replace('attachment_text', pattern, 'ꙮ')).withColumn("attachment_text",regexp_replace('attachment_text', '[^ꙮ]+', ''))

ranked = filtered.withColumn('Rank', length('attachment_text'))

sort = ranked.orderBy(ranked.Rank.desc()).limit(100)

sort_pd = sort.toPandas()
```

Currently, my "words" choices are to guarantee not getting any matches.  But whether I leave "words" like this or change them to something that will give a relatively small number of results, toPandas() still either "kills" the script or seems to be stuck processing forever.  However, if I comment out the final line that converts to pandas and run the remaining script it finishes almost immediately.

I also tried generating a much smaller simulated data set and ran the same script through it and it processes all the way to generating the csv in my s3 bucket with only minimal delay.

Edit:

```
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 100
+- LocalLimit 100
   +- Sort [Rank#3865 DESC NULLS LAST], true
      +- Project [attachment_md5_checksum#3659, attachment_filename#3660, attachment_text#3813, attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes#3662, notice_id#3663, title#3664, solicitation_number#3665, department_ind_agency#3666, cgac#3667, sub_tier#3668, fpds_code#3669, office#3670, aac_code#3671, posted_date#3672, type#3673, base_type#3674, archive_type#3675, archive_date#3676, set_aside_code#3677, set_aside#3678, response_deadline#3679, naice_code#3680, classification_code#3681, pop_street_address#3682, ... 28 more fields]
         +- Project [attachment_md5_checksum#3659, attachment_filename#3660, regexp_replace(attachment_text#3761, [^ꙮ]+, ) AS attachment_text#3813, attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes#3662, notice_id#3663, title#3664, solicitation_number#3665, department_ind_agency#3666, cgac#3667, sub_tier#3668, fpds_code#3669, office#3670, aac_code#3671, posted_date#3672, type#3673, base_type#3674, archive_type#3675, archive_date#3676, set_aside_code#3677, set_aside#3678, response_deadline#3679, naice_code#3680, classification_code#3681, pop_street_address#3682, ... 27 more fields]
            +- Project [attachment_md5_checksum#3659, attachment_filename#3660, regexp_replace(attachment_text#3661, \b(?=(\w+\W*){0,0}airfield\b)(\b(airfield)(\W+\w+\W*){0,3}){1,1}, ꙮ) AS attachment_text#3761, attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes#3662, notice_id#3663, title#3664, solicitation_number#3665, department_ind_agency#3666, cgac#3667, sub_tier#3668, fpds_code#3669, office#3670, aac_code#3671, posted_date#3672, type#3673, base_type#3674, archive_type#3675, archive_date#3676, set_aside_code#3677, set_aside#3678, response_deadline#3679, naice_code#3680, classification_code#3681, pop_street_address#3682, ... 27 more fields]
               +- Relation[attachment_md5_checksum#3659,attachment_filename#3660,attachment_text#3661,attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes#3662,notice_id#3663,title#3664,solicitation_number#3665,department_ind_agency#3666,cgac#3667,sub_tier#3668,fpds_code#3669,office#3670,aac_code#3671,posted_date#3672,type#3673,base_type#3674,archive_type#3675,archive_date#3676,set_aside_code#3677,set_aside#3678,response_deadline#3679,naice_code#3680,classification_code#3681,pop_street_address#3682,... 27 more fields] csv

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
attachment_md5_checksum: string, attachment_filename: string, attachment_text: string, attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes: string, notice_id: string, title: string, solicitation_number: string, department_ind_agency: string, cgac: string, sub_tier: string, fpds_code: string, office: string, aac_code: string, posted_date: string, type: string, base_type: string, archive_type: string, archive_date: string, set_aside_code: string, set_aside: string, response_deadline: string, naice_code: string, classification_code: string, pop_street_address: string, ... 28 more fields
GlobalLimit 100
+- LocalLimit 100
   +- Sort [Rank#3865 DESC NULLS LAST], true
      +- Project [attachment_md5_checksum#3659, attachment_filename#3660, attachment_text#3813, attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes#3662, notice_id#3663, title#3664, solicitation_number#3665, department_ind_agency#3666, cgac#3667, sub_tier#3668, fpds_code#3669, office#3670, aac_code#3671, posted_date#3672, type#3673, base_type#3674, archive_type#3675, archive_date#3676, set_aside_code#3677, set_aside#3678, response_deadline#3679, naice_code#3680, classification_code#3681, pop_street_address#3682, ... 28 more fields]
         +- Project [attachment_md5_checksum#3659, attachment_filename#3660, regexp_replace(attachment_text#3761, [^ꙮ]+, ) AS attachment_text#3813, attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes#3662, notice_id#3663, title#3664, solicitation_number#3665, department_ind_agency#3666, cgac#3667, sub_tier#3668, fpds_code#3669, office#3670, aac_code#3671, posted_date#3672, type#3673, base_type#3674, archive_type#3675, archive_date#3676, set_aside_code#3677, set_aside#3678, response_deadline#3679, naice_code#3680, classification_code#3681, pop_street_address#3682, ... 27 more fields]
            +- Project [attachment_md5_checksum#3659, attachment_filename#3660, regexp_replace(attachment_text#3661, \b(?=(\w+\W*){0,0}airfield\b)(\b(airfield)(\W+\w+\W*){0,3}){1,1}, ꙮ) AS attachment_text#3761, attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes#3662, notice_id#3663, title#3664, solicitation_number#3665, department_ind_agency#3666, cgac#3667, sub_tier#3668, fpds_code#3669, office#3670, aac_code#3671, posted_date#3672, type#3673, base_type#3674, archive_type#3675, archive_date#3676, set_aside_code#3677, set_aside#3678, response_deadline#3679, naice_code#3680, classification_code#3681, pop_street_address#3682, ... 27 more fields]
               +- Relation[attachment_md5_checksum#3659,attachment_filename#3660,attachment_text#3661,attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes#3662,notice_id#3663,title#3664,solicitation_number#3665,department_ind_agency#3666,cgac#3667,sub_tier#3668,fpds_code#3669,office#3670,aac_code#3671,posted_date#3672,type#3673,base_type#3674,archive_type#3675,archive_date#3676,set_aside_code#3677,set_aside#3678,response_deadline#3679,naice_code#3680,classification_code#3681,pop_street_address#3682,... 27 more fields] csv

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
GlobalLimit 100
+- LocalLimit 100
   +- Sort [Rank#3865 DESC NULLS LAST], true
      +- Project [attachment_md5_checksum#3659, attachment_filename#3660, regexp_replace(regexp_replace(attachment_text#3661, \b(?=(\w+\W*){0,0}airfield\b)(\b(airfield)(\W+\w+\W*){0,3}){1,1}, ꙮ), [^ꙮ]+, ) AS attachment_text#3813, attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes#3662, notice_id#3663, title#3664, solicitation_number#3665, department_ind_agency#3666, cgac#3667, sub_tier#3668, fpds_code#3669, office#3670, aac_code#3671, posted_date#3672, type#3673, base_type#3674, archive_type#3675, archive_date#3676, set_aside_code#3677, set_aside#3678, response_deadline#3679, naice_code#3680, classification_code#3681, pop_street_address#3682, ... 28 more fields]
         +- Relation[attachment_md5_checksum#3659,attachment_filename#3660,attachment_text#3661,attachment_urlsafe_base64_bytes#3662,notice_id#3663,title#3664,solicitation_number#3665,department_ind_agency#3666,cgac#3667,sub_tier#3668,fpds_code#3669,office#3670,aac_code#3671,posted_date#3672,type#3673,base_type#3674,archive_type#3675,archive_date#3676,set_aside_code#3677,set_aside#3678,response_deadline#3679,naice_code#3680,classification_code#3681,pop_street_address#3682,... 27 more fields] csv

== Physical Plan ==
TakeOrderedAndProject(limit=100, orderBy=[Rank#3865 DESC NULLS LAST], output=[field names,... 28 more fields])
+- *(1) Project [attachment_md5_checksum#3659, attachment_filename#3660, regexp_replace(regexp_replace(attachment_text#3661, \b(?=(\w+\W*){0,0}airfield\b)(\b(airfield)(\W+\w+\W*){0,3}){1,1}, ꙮ), [^ꙮ]+, ) AS field names ... 28 more fields]
   +- *(1) FileScan csv [field names,... 27 more fields] Batched: false, Format: CSV, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3a://..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [], ReadSchema: struct<attachment_md5_checksum:string,attachment_filename:string,attachment_text:string,attachmen...
```

Comment: Why don't you use `dataframe.write.csv` function?

Comment: Edited OP with clarification

Comment: And are you sure where is getting stuck is `toPandas()` task? Could you share your job details?

Comment: Added script to the OP

Comment: Execute this: `sort.explain(True)` and paste the output in your question

Comment: Posted output to OP

Comment: From my perspective there is no reason to `toPandas()` being the failure, you described that has a large dataset, did you check if your cluster has cores/mem enough to filter your data?